# How to make text on a website appear handwritten, but unreadable

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

I have a 'guestbook' image on my webpage that I use as the login box.  Keeping true to the theme, I display the names of each person who has logged in to read that particular article and list their names before the login boxes (trying to create the feel of an actual guestbook).  Of course, some users may want to log in but not have their real name displayed, so I added a checkbox allowing them to mark their name for obfuscation.

I thought the smoothest way to integrate this, since there is some value to having the correct number of 'signatures' on the 'guestbook', would be to have normal names appear in a standard script font (such as Brush Script), then have the lines for the 'hidden' names have what looks like handwriting, but that isn't actually readable.

The only way I could think to do this would be to find an unreadable font, define it in the css for the browser to download, then apply it to the hidden names.  For good measure I can replace the real names with a random selection of "John Doe", "Jane Doe", "Jayne Doe", etc in case anyone views the source.  However, after an hour of searching I've been unable to locate a font that meets my criteria, and I'm wondering if there's some better way to handle this problem.

So I was hoping someone could either suggest a font that might work for my needs, or suggest a better solution.  Thank you.

Comment: Why not simply use a [background image](https://www.google.com/search?q=unreadable+signature&hl=en&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=xyv7T-7mBYGK6QG746HbBg&ved=0CEgQsAQ&biw=1920&bih=955)?

Comment: There are several suggestions of using an image instead of a font, and that is a valid approach.  However, I must still find an unreadable font to use in that case (suggestions most welcome).

Comment: Even if you could find an "unreadable" font anyone who knows which font you are using will be able to easily decode the names - so that won't give your users their privacy...

Comment: Even if a font is unreadable, they'd still be able to copy paste the text.....

Comment: @RobertTrickey that's a good point. IMO, mapping random letters is the best way to go.

Comment: I will be replacing the real names with generic ones (ie: John Doe).  The unreadability part is simply to maintain the look and feel.  If necessary I'll just write out a bunch of John Does, Jane Does, and other generic names in Brush Script, but that's my fallback solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a [**free font set**](http://www.letterror.com/foundry/goodies/index.html) I've come across you might be interested in for both PC and MAC.

**The Printed Word Font:**

[image]

**The Written Word Font:**

[image]

Both samples above are in `12px`.

Due to the small image dimensions, they are seen at 100% distortion free quality (pun intended).

Use the built in [**Windows Font Map Viewer**](http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/accents/charmap.html) or [**MAC Font Book**](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2509) to view all characters of the font file.

Comment: Arttronics, that seems just about perfect.  The sizing seems a little off, but I'll give it a shot in the application tonight or tomorrow and let you know how it goes.  Thanks!  :)

Comment: If the sizing is a little off, use a different `font-size` for your requirements. Also, using the character map font viewer will help you choose the various word segments, as some range from a comma in length to a full size word per each key press. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If the name is to be unreadable, make some images in Photoshop of unreadable names and load them up randomly with in place of the actual name. That would be much easier and more flexible than using CSS and a special font.

Comment: That's a good idea. In short, for each letter just load an image instead of displaying the actual letter in the code. Be sure to not leave code traces or people could look deeper into it.

Comment: Thank you, I agree.  Though this suggestion, like my original plan, relies on there being a font out there designed to look like handwriting but not be readable.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know of any unreadable fonts other than fonts like Wingdings, but you might try using Photoshop or Gimp to pixelate or blur some gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

How about scrambling the name's letters or replacing them altogether? You can just use random letters for a person that doesn't wanna share their name. For example 'John' could become 'ojhn' or simply 'sghj'.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts, Joseph.  Buth thank you for the suggestion MrBigshot.

Comment: consider how we concieve words - for the most part, we don't notice the order of inner letters, so obfucsation of this sort might not be very effcetive. e.g. the words *conceive*, *obfuscation*, and *effective* in this comment.

Comment: haha yeah I figured that out myself, which is why I suggested just random letters.